# Как отсортировать элементы строки по трем спискам?

Tags: python, list, for

Изучаю Python не так давно и не могу решить поставленную задачу с помощью цикла For
Задача: написать программу, которая сортирует содержимое строки по трем спискам: Символы, буквы, цифры. *Если нет символа\буквы\цифры в строке создать пустой список.*

Делал через Enumerate, но получался очень длинный код, через цикл For код должен быть объективно короче, но выдавало ошибку с несколькими условиями If

Ввод например 0a1b2.c 3%d4#e 5f,6g7h\8i9j

Вывод

```
['.', ' ', '%', '#', ' ', ',', '\']

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Задачу вижу, а в чем проблема, где вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос как решит данную задачу используя цикл For

Comment: Наводящий ответ пользователя Глеб помог, никто не просил делать за меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте преобразовать это в нормальный код, в процессе поймете, как решается задача.

```
from string import digits as d, ascii_lowercase as al, punctuation as p
lambda: [[i for i in input() if i in x] for x in (p, al, d)]
```

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, спасибо Глеб за помощь, первоначальная ошибка так же была найдена.